# What is this switch called?

Tags: pcb, switches, identification

I'm trying to fix a bad switch, what is this blue switch called?  It has 6 pins and clicks on and off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's probably a DPDT latching pushbutton although from the bottom tracks it looks like it's connected differently to what I'd expect depending on what the function of the switch is, is it power or something else? Any chance of either a diagram of how it connects or maybe uncrop a bit and indicate where power comes in? It's also worth adding the voltage it's running at.

Comment: looks similar to [this one](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/electromechanical/switches-key-pad/push-button-switch-dc-30v-0-1a-dpdt-7x7mm.html)  or [this 6mm one](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/electromechanical/switches-key-pad/push-button-switch-latching-dpdt-0-5a-50vdc-6x6mm.html)

Comment: First try reflowing the solder on the pins and check the PCB for broken tracks - the centre left joint shows signs of a crack. Pressing the switch can flex the PCB and cause failures, while the switch itself might be OK!

Comment: @BrianDrummond The switch was stuck so I replaced it entirely.  I'll remember that for next time though.

Comment: @pault Thanks for the link, it ended up being a 7x7mm DPDT.  I bought it from that store too! (along with $5 in random capacitors to get the order minimum covered :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **DPDT**-Double pole, single throw
**Vertical Push Switch**, as you can see [here](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?pv130=4&FV=fff40011,fff80061&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25).

You can check a datasheet example, [datasheet](http://spec.e-switch.com/D-D/D300000B.pdf)

Its two switches inside one package.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXV6aV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In your case the pins 1-4, 2-5 and 3-6 are connected togheter.

The pins 1 and 4 are the Normally Closed, and the pins 3 and 6 are the Normally Open, the pins 2 and 5 are the commom pins for each circuit.

Comment: It ended up being a 7mm DPDT switch, with the pins connected like you said.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!